# Editable frontend solution for a 2d array in a Django form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, frontend

I am building a Django app, where a model "Foo" has a ManyToMany relation with "Bar" like this:

```
Foo(Model):
    [field1]
    [field2]
    ...

Bar(Model)
    [general_field1]
    [general_field2]
    ...

FooBar(Model)
    ForeignKey(Foo)
    ForeignKey(Bar)
    [specific_field1]
    [specific_field2]
    ...
```

The main model is Foo. I display each Foo in a template with it's fields and a 2D list of FooBars with general and specific fields (ordered list with several FooBars on each line).

I need a solution to save this to the database (Problem 1) and more importantly to create a form or custom input fields for the user to populate it (Problem 2).

The user should see (after the input fields for the Foo fields) some kind of blank list. There should be a search field with prerendered Bar models beneath it. As the user types in the search field the results beneath it are filtered. If the user selects a Bar a modal should open with fields to populate the "specific" fields for the actual FooBar (the general fields of the Bar are preset). After that the FooBar should appear in the list and the process continues. If the search result is blank (the user can't find the desired Foo) a "Create new Foo" option should appear in the results. Clicking on it opens a modal with fields to populate the new Bar with the "general" fields and also the new FooBar with the "specific" fields. On completion the new Bar is saved on the backend and the new FooBar appears in the frontend list.
There should also be a "New line" option to jump to finish the line in the list and jump to the next one.

The user should be able to edit this list. Delete FooBars or (if it is possible) drag and drop to new location. Or stick new FooBars between existing ones.

After everything is ready the user should submit the whole Foo form and in the backend the Foo is saved with all its FooBars.

The user should be able to open the Foo to edit. This should open an edit view where all the Foo fields and the list with the FooBars are pre-populated. The user should be able to stick in, delete, or edit FooBars on any location.

I know it is much and pretty specific but I have a vision, yet not enough experience with development. Can somebody help me with this?

For "Problem 1" My first approach was to make an "order" field in FooBar. The template then opens the specific section with `<ol><li>` and renders each FooBar in order, with a special FooBar named "Break" which renders a `</li><li>`. Then i close everything with `</li></ol>`
This works well in the database and view but I have no idea how should I populate it through frontend in an intuitive way.
I think it could be better implemented with x and y "coordinates". It depends on the solution for Problem 2.

For "Problem 2" i am able to create the inputs for the Foo fields but I have no Idea how to make that complicated FooBars list.